# How to get large profile picture from Facebook API (using Javascript)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this code:

```
FB.api('/me', 
{fields: 'id, first_name, last_name, email, link, gender, picture'}, 
function(response) {

Pass data to php file which saves it in the database

}
```

The picture field contains an url to a 50x50 image. How can I get an url to a larger picture?

I have been looking at the documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/
but I am still confused.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help

```
$facebook->api(me?fields=picture.width(800).height(800))
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually solved this, the answer was `picture.type(large)` :)

Comment: Thanks i will try it too